# Android memory efficient collection for keeping tokenized strings

Tags: java, android, collections

In my project I'm trying to load a 600KB file from assets folder containing tokens of Strings.

I need these tokens to be available/search/contains at o(1) or any constant time.

I started of with `HashSet` - but it blows up the String data to 10MB - causing Out of Memory issues

then, switched to `ArrayList` - but that also blows to 6MB.

I tried using primitive `String`, but when I build it from `StringBuffer` - the inherent issue with `append` method comes in - causing Out of Memory issue.

So, my main concern still remains with this data:

- Its originally 600KB - so collection should keep it well within 1 or 2MB
- Lookup should be preferably within O(1)

Is there any good Java collection(even from any other library) that can help me?

Comment: the size issue relates to Java Strings rather than collection

Answer (score 0):

Representing these tokens in memory in 1 to 2Mb *and also* supporting `O(1)` lookup will be really hard.  None of the standard collection types would be able to do this for you, 
and I'm not aware of any 3rd-party Java library that will either.  (The [S-Space](http://fozziethebeat.github.com/S-Space/) project has a [`TrieSet`](http://fozziethebeat.github.com/S-Space/apidocs/edu/ucla/sspace/util/TrieSet.html) implementation, but I looked at the code, and I'm pretty sure it won't meet either your space or performance requirements ...)

Assuming that the characters in the string are ASCII, then turning them into String objects immediately doubles the size (`byte` -> `char`), and then you need to add 32 bytes of overhead for each string.  Then if you put the strings into a `HashSet` you need roughly 32 additional bytes for each entry in the set.

With a `ArrayList<String>` the per-entry overhead is 4 bytes, but lookup is now `O(N)` ... or `O(logN)` if you keep the list ordered and use binary search.  Either way you are still way over your memory budget.

To stay under your budget you are going to have to use a custom hash table data structure that is optimized for memory usage *and* hold your character data in memory as a single array of bytes.

Here is a hypothetical implementation.

1. Allocate an `int[]` to be hash array.  The size should be a prime number that is roughly half to a fifth of the number of tokens.
2. Allocate a `byte[]` big enough to hold the file of tokens.
3. For each slot in the hash array:

   - scan the file byte-wise looking for all tokens whose hashcode maps to the slot,
   - copy each token to the byte array and follow it with a terminator byte,
   - if you found any tokens, write the byte array offset of the start of the first token to the hash array slot ... otherwise set it to `-1`.
4. To do a lookup:

   - convert the test string to bytes,
   - hash the bytes of your test string (using the same hash algorithm as above), and map it to a hash slot,
   - starting at the offset in the hash slot, compare the bytes of the test string against the bytes in the `byte[]`.  Repeat until you get either a match, or you reach the offset in the *next* hash array element.

As you can see, the process of filling the `byte[]` involves scanning the input file multiple times.  However this could be done before hand, and the input file could then be updated to contain the bytes in the required order.

The space usage would be one byte per byte of string data + 1 byte overhead per string + 4 bytes for each slot in the primary hash array (+ sundry `O(1)` overheads).  Lookups are `O(1)` on average, but the constant depends on the hash array size.  (The larger, the better.)

The big drawbacks of the above design are:

- creating the data structure is expensive
- the data structure cannot be updated in a space or time efficient fashion
- if you iterate the set, you have to create a bunch of String objects to represent the entries ... or expose the byte array and offsets.

Answer (score 0):

That's an interesting problem! I normally use the HashMap class in the util package for storage such as this. Your problem may not easily fit in the memory space of an android device so I will suggest an alternative.

For storage android devices typically use solid state such as SD cards which are typically fairly fast, so why not leave most of the data on the disk in the assets folder until needed? You could construct a class to cache the most frequently used results and modifying data should be reasonable as well. If this doesn't suite perhaps you could use the data management facilities available in the android SDK such as sqlite which will do some of the hard work for you.

If you can avoid using strings that's often a better option. Strings can be very expensive to manipulate. If you use another data type (or even an char or byte array) you will probably find the code a bit more complex but more efficient in terms of memory.

Comment: I can try storing all the tokens a char[] with say "," as a delimeter, but then will I be able to search a word at O(1) -- any library or Algo/Data Structure that you can suggest.

Comment: If you were to create an index into the array to tell you where the delimiters are that would be possible. Otherwise O(n) to find the delimiter in a n sized array.

Comment: Another option I thought you could try is to use a HashMap. Use an appropriate key for the tokens and then you just need to look it up when you need it. HashMaps are pretty fast, but not as efficient as arrays for memory space. But seeing as you can store each token as a separate entity you can skip storing the delimiters (unless they are important). If you run out of memory using this method you can use the HashMap as a cache, if something isn't found in it retrieve it from disk and store it in the map. You have to be sure to occasionally delete stuff out of the map doing this.